# accept() return value when there is no pending connection

Tags: linux, networking

I make simple server.c that doing this :

1. listening to port 7705.
2. accept the incoming connection from "Client-x".
3. while there is no pending connection, then receive data from "Client-1".
4. if there is pending connection from another client then goto step second.

and this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port ..\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
         p error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    accpt:
     while (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen) < 0) 
    {
    /* i don't know return value for "there is no pending connection" in accept() function, so i use -1 value" */
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    ....... // Process data, and etc //
    }
    goto accept
     }
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Everytime you type `goto` I kill a kitten. Please, think of the kittens

Answer (score 2):

Blame it on precedence.
Original:

```
while (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen) < 0) { ...}
```

Fixed version:

```
while ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen)) < 0) { ...}
   // ^           ?                                                       ^ ?
```

Without the extra parentheses, the `<` takes precedence ( *binds tighter than* ) over the `=`, and the statement would be evaluated as `while (newsockfd = (accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen) < 0) ) { ...}` , which assigns the result of the `<` comparison to newsockfd, which is clearly not the intention.

The above is a good reason to avoid compound assignments, and instead use an idiom like this:

```
while (1) {
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
  if (newsockfd >=  0) break;
  ...}
```

BTW: in the OQ, the direction of the `<` is also completely wrong; the stuff inside the `while {...}` seems to handle an incoming connection, and that would need a filedescriptor `>= 0` .

Comment: Also a good reason to enable warnings, GCC says `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value` with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no pending connections, `accept` *won't* return; it will block until there is a connection, and then it will return. You can make it return immediately by making the socket non-blocking, but by default, they are blocking, and the aforementioned behavior holds.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of putting the listening socket into non-blocking mode, you can use `select()` with a short timeout to detect when a new connection is pending before then accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

> i don't know return value for "there is no pending connection" in accept() function

There isn't one. It doesn't return until there is a connection to accept. It blocks.